# Syntax Highlighting in iPython Notebook Markdown Cell

Tags: ipython, markdown, syntax-highlighting, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to get a Markdown cell in iPython Notebooks to highlight syntax in code blocks?

For instance, in GitHub, one can get the desired effect via the following.

````
```python
>>>print('hello')
```
````

Comment: Does not seem this is present in current release. Submit a feature request?

Comment: I am interested in that as well

Comment: And now it certainly works :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [GitHub Flavored Markdown-style of denoting code using the triple-backtick is now supported in IPython master branch on GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3101), and so will be included in the 1.0 release.

As Jakob noted, even prior to this, you could use regular markdown for code, in which you just need to indent your code by four spaces, and this continues to be a valid way of displaying code in your IPython notebook.

Comment: I have to add explicit language tag, e.g.  \`\`\`py  ... \`\`\` for syntax highlighting to kick in.

Answer (score 1):

using IPython 0.13.1 syntax highlighting is as easy as (in a markdown cell):

```
some text

    def foo():
        print 'bar'
        return 0

some text
```

Just, use a blank line before and indent the code (see example notebooks shipped with Ipython). This works for Python and some other languages.

Comment: Doesn't seem to highlight syntax any longer :(

Answer (score 1):

In IPython 7.2.0 notebooks you can use:

`` Text `code` text ``

in a markdown cell to print highlighted code inline.