# Syntax highlighting by default for indented code in a notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebooks have executable code cells, which are automatically colorized, and markdown cells that can can display (non-executable) code indented by four spaces.

Contrary to what is claimed in the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794698/syntax-highlighting-in-ipython-notebook-markdown-cell), my indented Python code is not highlighted. However, highlighting is available and I can get it by enclosing code in git-style triple backticks and specifying `python` as the language:

````
This is a single markdown cell.

Code indented 4 spaces:

    import re
    "hello"

Surrounded by triple backticks:

```python
import re
"hello"
```
````

This is displayed like this:

> [image]

Is there a way to enable Python syntax highlighting for indented code, e.g. by adding something to the notebook's metadata?

PS. I am using `jupyter` 4.2.1. Indented code was never colorized with earlier versions, either (on Firefox).